# where condition for null records

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

If my field is null then i need condition

```
select * from data where :P2_EMPLOYEE is null then MANAGER = 'Alex'
```

Comment: `... where ((:P2_EMPLOYEE is null and MANAGER = 'Alex') or (:P2_EMPLOYEE is not null))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`coalesce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617):

```
select * 
from data 
where MANAGER = coalesce(:P2_EMPLOYEE, 'Alex')
```

Answer (score 0):

A few other options (beside the ones you've already seen):

```
where manager = case when :P2_EMPLOYEE is null then 'Alex'
                     else :P2_EMPLOYEE
                end;

where manager = decode(:P2_EMPLOYEE, null, 'Alex', :P2_EMPLOYEE)

where manager = nvl(:P2_EMPLOYEE, 'Alex')
```